# Code First Model Definition

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I have the following models,do I define it Ok?

1. User is the main Entity and can have 0..1 to * (zero /one to many relationship ) address.

2.User can have have 0..1 to 1 (one to one userPass )

This is the main table

```
public class User
{

    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email    { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string PhoneWork { get; set; }
    public string WorkingAt { get; set; }

    public virtual UserPass UserPass { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class ConfigModelDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserPass> UserPasses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOptional(c => c.Addresses).WithRequired(addresses => new User());

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOptional(c => c.UserPass).WithRequired(pass => new User());

    }
}
```

Address Class

```
public class Address
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Userpass class

```
public class UserPass
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

i also created classes same as above but can it create relationship directly on database table?

Answer (score 1):

at first I offer you to use data annotation instead of fluent api always.

then correct AddressClass like below:

```
public class Address
        {
            [Key]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            [ForeignKey("UserId")]
            public User User { get; set; }
            public string UserId { get; set; }
            public string UserAddress { get; set; }
        }
```

This will create Ralationship.
for more details please read [Code First DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg193958.aspx)